# Ошибка 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, классы, стек

Пишу стек на плюсах. Exeшник компилится и крашится с ошибкой 0xC0000005. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
template<class T> struct Stack
{
    Stack()          : LAST(int()) {}
    Stack(int ssize) : LAST(ssize) { DATA = new T [ssize]; }

    Stack push(T n)
    {
        LAST++;
        realloc(DATA, LAST*sizeof(T));
        DATA[LAST - 1] = n;
        return *this;
    }
    Stack pop()
    {
        LAST--;
        realloc(DATA, LAST*sizeof(T));
        return *this;
    }
    T top()
    {
        return DATA[LAST - 1];
    }

    T *DATA;
    int LAST;
};

int main()
{
    Stack<int> st;
    st.push(10);
    st.push(20);
    st.pop();
    int a = st.top();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Основная проблема заключается в неверном использовании функции **realloc**. Из
обнаруженных ошибок:

1. - У вас при первом вызове метода **push** эта функция получает
     неинициализованный указатель. Следует обнулить поле **data**.
   - Первый аргумент этой функции должен быть указателем, полученным от
     **malloc** или **realloc**.
2. Возвращаемое значение **realloc** можно проверять на **NULL**, а кроме
   того, надо обязательно присваивать полю **data**. Потому что, если функция
   переместит массив в другое место памяти, она вернёт новый указатель на
   него.

По поводу последнего пункта компилятор GCC даже выдаёт предупреждение

> ```
> t.cpp: In member function ‘Stack<T> Stack<T>::push(T) [with T = int]’:
> t.cpp:11:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘void* realloc(void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
>          realloc(DATA, LAST*sizeof(T));
>          ^
> ```

*P.S.: пожалуйста, имена целиком из заглавных букв давайте только константам.*